# Find all the continuous functions that satisfy $[f(t)]^2=F(t)-F(0)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, recurrence-relations

I need to find all the continuous functions $f$ such that
$$
[f(t)]^2=\int_0^t f(s) ds
$$
**Attempt:**

Since 
$$ 
f(t)\leq [f(t)]^2+c, \, \, \forall c \geq \frac14$$
we have

$$
f(t)\leq c+ \int_0^t f(s)ds $$
Now, Gronwall's Lemma gives
$$
f(t) \leq c+ \int_0^t c \,e^{t-\tau}d\tau \iff$$
$$ f(t) \leq c \, e^t, \, \,\forall c\geq \frac14$$

Given that these steps were correct, is this inequality the final answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just observe that $f(0)=0$ and then take the derivative
$$
2ff'=f\implies f=0\lor 2f'=1,~f=\frac t2.
$$
As per a hint of Ian in a prior comment, you can also combine a segment where $f=0$ and then the nullity of $f(t)(2f'(t)-1)=0$ switches to the second factor generating a solution $f(t)=\frac12\max(0, t-a)$.

Comment: $f$ is not necessarily differentiable, just continuous.

Comment: But $f^2$ is differentiable.And the square root is only not differentiable for $f=0$. So separate into segments where $f=0$ where then also $f'=0$ and other segments where $f\ne0$ is differentiable per chain rule.

Comment: If it's proven like this, I guess your solution is legit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Lemma use to prove the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^xf(t)dt=f(x)$$

Here we have $[f(t)]^2=\int_0^tf(s)ds.$

Take the $t$ derivative of both sides.

So $2f(t)f'(t)-f(t)=0=f(t)[2f'(t)-1].$

So either $f(t)=0$, or $2f'(t)-1=0\implies f(t)=t/2+c$.

Comment: What Lemma should I use?

Comment: It's sometimes called First fundamental Theorem of Calculus:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part