# Find all continuous functions that satisfy: $\forall x\ge0, (f(x))^2=\int_0^x f(t)dt$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

I've found 2 almost-duplicates of this question:

- [Find all the continuous functions that satisfy $[f(t)]^2=F(t)-F(0)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2990400/find-all-the-continuous-functions-that-satisfy-ft2-ft-f0)
- [If $\int_0^xf(t)dt=[f(x)]^2$ but $f(x)\neq 0$, what is $f(x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1392520/if-int-0xftdt-fx2-but-fx-neq-0-what-is-fx)

However, the solutions assume that $f$ is differentiable. I want to find *all* continuous functions that satisfy it, differentiable or not.

So we already have:

- $f(x)=x/2$
- $f(x)=0$

Can we find other continuous functions? If not, how can we prove that no more exist?

Comment: It looks to me like $f$ is non-negative on $[0, \infty)$. Which means that it's motonically increasing. So it must be differentiable _almost_ everywhere.

Comment: A complete answer must look into possibilities of gluing together different f's. So, one might have f(x)=0 for all negative x and the f(x)=x/2 for positive x.

Comment: @BehnamEsmayli Negative $x$ aren't considered, I think.

Comment: you can go up to x<2 and then switch to the other branch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous, then $\int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt$ is differentiable by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Thus, the equal quantity $(f(x))^2$ is differentiable (and note that it's nonnegative). Then $\sqrt{(f(x))^2}=|f(x)|$ is differentiable wherever $f(x)\ne0$ by the Chain Rule.

Since $f$ is continuous, it can't jump from positive to negative without crossing $0$ (by the intermediate value theorem). So $f$ is positive/negative on entire intervals. On an interval where $f$ is nonzero, $|f(x)|$ is $f(x)$ on the whole interval or $-f(x)$ on the whole interval. In the former case, $f(x)$ is differentiable on the interval. In the latter case, it's still differentiable on the interval by the constant multiple rule.

In conclusion, a continuous $f$ satisfying that equation must also be differentiable at any point where it's not zero. However, this alone doesn't rule out $f$ changing direction at points where $f=0$.

Indeed, where $f$ is nonzero and hence differentiable, we can differentiate both sides as in [DeepSea's answer to the linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1392761/26369) to get $f(x)=x/2+C$ on that interval. However, any such function only attains the value $0$ at one point, $x=-2C$ so the function can't return to $0$ on two sides of being $x/2+C$. Also, we must have $f(0)=0$ because of the integral. Therefore, the only ways to stitch together functions of this form and locations where $f=0$ are:

1. $f(x)\equiv0$
2. $f(x)\equiv x/2$
3. $f(x)=\cases{0\text{ if }x<a\\(x-a)/2\text{ if }x\ge a}$ for some $a\ge0$
4. $f(x)=\cases{(x-a)/2\text{ if }x<a\\0\text{ if }x\ge a}$ for some $a\le0$

Comment: I don't fully understand. $|f|$ is only differentiable at points $x$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$. Also, what do you mean by "$|f(x)|$ is either $f(x)$ on the whole interval or $-f(x)$ on the whole interval". Clearly, in a neighbourhood of $0$, $f(x) = \frac{x}{2}$ doesn't satisfy this. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: @peek-a-boo Sorry, you're right. $|f|$ is only guaranteed to be differentiable where $f$ is nonzero. If $f$ is positive somewhere, it's positive on an interval because it's continuous, and on any such interval, $|f|\equiv f$. And similarly for negative. So in the example of $x/2$, I meant something like "on $[0,\infty)$, $|f|=f$, and on $(-\infty,0]$, $|f|=-f$." More importantly, my conclusion should be something like "on each interval where $f$ isn't $0$, it's differentiable." To fully settle the question, we'd have to rule out weird cases where $f$ isn't differentiable at $0$.

Comment: Just a minor nit-pick: I don't think we are considering negative $x$. At least, the restraint isn't applicable there, so the function could be whatever. Together with $f(0) = 0$, this seems to rule out your fourth option.